# USB/USB-C combo flash drive mounts and works on Windows and Android, but not macOS

Tags: windows, macos, mount, usb-flash-drive, bad-sectors

I have [a flash drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0842P5GBQ) that supports both USB and USB-C. The problem with this flash drive is that it works on Windows, but not on macOS. Specifically:

- The drive is exFAT-formatted and does not have encryption on it.
- The drive works as expected on both USB ports on Windows.
- This drive also works as expected when connected to my Android phone via USB-C (i.e. directly, not with a cable). I just copied some pet photos onto it.
- The drive *did* work on macOS at one point; I was able to copy files onto it without issue.
- I cannot mount or format the drive on macOS.
- Running `fsck_exfat /dev/disk2s1` on the drive returns the error message `fsck_exfat: Can't open /dev/rdisk2s1: Operation not permitted`.
- I've backed up the files that the drive contained onto a separate disk drive. These files were copied without incident, and their contents do not appear to be corrupted.

I formatted the drive as ExFAT again, then verified it with [H2testw](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/77/). It reported no errors:

```
Test finished without errors.
You can now delete the test files *.h2w or verify them again.
Writing speed: 22.6 MByte/s
Reading speed: 86.5 MByte/s
H2testw v1.4
```

However, [FakeFlashTest](https://rmprepusb.com/tutorials/007-all-about-fake-sd-cards-and-usb-flash-drives) did identify problems:

```
FAKEFLASHTEST v1.1.4  [SSi]
[DRIVE 7]     114.5GiB USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1            
FFT - Quick Size Test (destructive)
L:     (no label)   [DRIVE 7]     114.5GiB USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1            

Writing marker blocks to drive 7 at 200MiB intervals.
*** ERROR *** writing to drive at Sector 240316334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 240316334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 239906734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 239497134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 239087534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 238677934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 238268334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 237858734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 237449134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 237039534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 236629934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 236220334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 235810734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 235401134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 234991534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 234581934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 234172334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 233762734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 233353134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 232943534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 232533934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 232124334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 231714734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 231305134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 230895534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 230485934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 230076334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 229666734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 229257134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 228847534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 228437934
5% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 228028334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 227618734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 227209134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 226799534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 226389934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 225980334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 225570734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 225161134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 224751534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 224341934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 223932334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 223522734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 223113134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 222703534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 222293934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 221884334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 221474734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 221065134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 220655534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 220245934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 219836334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 219426734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 219017134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 218607534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 218197934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 217788334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 217378734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 216969134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 216559534
10% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 216149934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 215740334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 215330734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 214921134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 214511534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 214101934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 213692334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 213282734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 212873134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 212463534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 212053934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 211644334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 211234734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 210825134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 210415534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 210005934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 209596334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 209186734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 208777134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 208367534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 207957934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 207548334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 207138734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 206729134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 206319534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 205909934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 205500334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 205090734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 204681134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 204271534
15% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 203861934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 203452334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 203042734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 202633134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 202223534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 201813934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 201404334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 200994734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 200585134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 200175534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 199765934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 199356334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 198946734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 198537134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 198127534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 197717934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 197308334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 196898734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 196489134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 196079534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 195669934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 195260334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 194850734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 194441134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 194031534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 193621934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 193212334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 192802734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 192393134
20% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 191983534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 191573934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 191164334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 190754734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 190345134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 189935534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 189525934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 189116334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 188706734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 188297134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 187887534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 187477934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 187068334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 186658734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 186249134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 185839534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 185429934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 185020334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 184610734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 184201134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 183791534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 183381934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 182972334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 182562734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 182153134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 181743534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 181333934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 180924334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 180514734
25% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 180105134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 179695534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 179285934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 178876334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 178466734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 178057134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 177647534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 177237934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 176828334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 176418734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 176009134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 175599534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 175189934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 174780334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 174370734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 173961134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 173551534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 173141934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 172732334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 172322734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 171913134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 171503534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 171093934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 170684334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 170274734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 169865134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 169455534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 169045934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 168636334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 168226734
30% complete  - 0 min 3 sec  remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 167817134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 167407534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 166997934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 166588334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 166178734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 165769134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 165359534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 164949934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 164540334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 164130734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 163721134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 163311534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 162901934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 162492334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 162082734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 161673134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 161263534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 160853934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 160444334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 160034734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 159625134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 159215534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 158805934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 158396334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 157986734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 157577134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 157167534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 156757934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 156348334
35% complete  - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 155938734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 155529134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 155119534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 154709934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 154300334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 153890734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 153481134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 153071534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 152661934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 152252334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 151842734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 151433134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 151023534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 150613934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 150204334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 149794734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 149385134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 148975534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 148565934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 148156334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 147746734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 147337134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 146927534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 146517934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 146108334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 145698734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 145289134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 144879534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 144469934
40% complete  - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 144060334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 143650734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 143241134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 142831534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 142421934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 142012334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 141602734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 141193134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 140783534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 140373934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 139964334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 139554734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 139145134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 138735534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 138325934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 137916334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 137506734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 137097134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 136687534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 136277934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 135868334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 135458734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 135049134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 134639534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 134229934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 133820334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 133410734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 133001134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 132591534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 132181934
45% complete  - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 131772334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 131362734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 130953134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 130543534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 130133934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 129724334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 129314734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 128905134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 128495534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 128085934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 127676334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 127266734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 126857134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 126447534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 126037934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 125628334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 125218734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 124809134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 124399534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 123989934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 123580334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 123170734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 122761134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 122351534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 121941934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 121532334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 121122734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 120713134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 120303534
50% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 119893934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 119484334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 119074734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 118665134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 118255534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 117845934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 117436334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 117026734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 116617134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 116207534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 115797934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 115388334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 114978734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 114569134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 114159534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 113749934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 113340334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 112930734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 112521134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 112111534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 111701934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 111292334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 110882734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 110473134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 110063534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 109653934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 109244334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 108834734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 108425134
55% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 108015534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 107605934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 107196334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 106786734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 106377134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 105967534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 105557934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 105148334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 104738734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 104329134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 103919534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 103509934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 103100334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 102690734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 102281134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 101871534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 101461934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 101052334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 100642734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 100233134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 99823534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 99413934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 99004334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 98594734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 98185134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 97775534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 97365934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 96956334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 96546734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 96137134
60% complete  - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 95727534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 95317934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 94908334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 94498734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 94089134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 93679534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 93269934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 92860334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 92450734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 92041134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 91631534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 91221934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 90812334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 90402734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 89993134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 89583534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 89173934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 88764334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 88354734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 87945134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 87535534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 87125934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 86716334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 86306734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 85897134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 85487534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 85077934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 84668334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 84258734
65% complete  - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 83849134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 83439534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 83029934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 82620334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 82210734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 81801134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 81391534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 80981934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 80572334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 80162734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 79753134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 79343534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 78933934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 78524334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 78114734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 77705134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 77295534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 76885934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 76476334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 76066734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 75657134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 75247534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 74837934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 74428334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 74018734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 73609134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 73199534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 72789934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 72380334
70% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 71970734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 71561134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 71151534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 70741934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 70332334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 69922734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 69513134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 69103534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 68693934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 68284334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 67874734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 67465134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 67055534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 66645934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 66236334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 65826734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 65417134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 65007534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 64597934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 64188334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 63778734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 63369134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 62959534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 62549934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 62140334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 61730734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 61321134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 60911534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 60501934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 60092334
75% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 59682734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 59273134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 58863534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 58453934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 58044334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 57634734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 57225134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 56815534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 56405934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 55996334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 55586734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 55177134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 54767534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 54357934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 53948334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 53538734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 53129134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 52719534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 52309934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 51900334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 51490734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 51081134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 50671534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 50261934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 49852334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 49442734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 49033134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 48623534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 48213934
80% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 47804334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 47394734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 46985134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 46575534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 46165934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 45756334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 45346734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 44937134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 44527534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 44117934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 43708334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 43298734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 42889134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 42479534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 42069934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 41660334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 41250734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 40841134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 40431534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 40021934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 39612334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 39202734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 38793134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 38383534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 37973934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 37564334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 37154734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 36745134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 36335534
85% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 35925934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 35516334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 35106734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 34697134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 34287534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 33877934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 33468334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 33058734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 32649134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 32239534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 31829934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 31420334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 31010734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 30601134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 30191534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 29781934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 29372334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 28962734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 28553134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 28143534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 27733934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 27324334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 26914734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 26505134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 26095534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 25685934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 25276334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 24866734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 24457134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 24047534
90% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 23637934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 23228334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 22818734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 22409134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 21999534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 21589934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 21180334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 20770734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 20361134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 19951534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 19541934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 19132334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 18722734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 18313134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 17903534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 17493934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 17084334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 16674734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 16265134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 15855534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 15445934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 15036334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 14626734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 14217134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 13807534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 13397934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 12988334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 12578734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 12169134
95% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 11759534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 11349934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 10940334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 10530734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 10121134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 9711534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 9301934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 8892334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 8482734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 8073134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 7663534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 7253934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 6844334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 6434734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 6025134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 5615534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 5205934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 4796334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 4386734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 3977134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 3567534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 3157934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 2748334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 2338734
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 1929134
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 1519534
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 1109934
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 700334
WRITE ERROR: Sector = 290734
100% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
Reading back marker blocks...
5% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
10% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
15% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
20% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
25% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
30% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
35% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
40% complete - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
45% complete - 0 min 2 sec  remaining
50% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
55% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
60% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
65% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
70% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
75% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
80% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
85% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
90% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
95% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
Memory tested in blocks of 409600 sectors [586sectors checked].

BAD MEMORY from sector 700334 (341.9599MiB) to sector 240316334 (117,341.9599Mib)

WARNING: no memory detected at one or more locations.
Test took 4 seconds.
586 sectors checked.
                         *** FAILED ***

DEVICE HAS DUPLICATE OR BAD BLOCKS!

Recommended maximum usable partition size: 141.9599Mib (approx. Last good Sector=700334)

Unplug and re-connect the drive, then reformat it using Windows or RMPrepUSB.
```

Any tips?

Comment: Check that the photos you copied from the droid are now also visible when you put it in the PC. Also see if it appears under Disk Utility on the Mac [Cmd/2 so you can see devices as well as volumes] & whether it can be mounted manually. Also, on any device that can see this info - how full is it?

Comment: And for good measure do an error correction in Windows.

Comment: @Tetsujin Photos appear on Windows without issue. Windows reports the drive as 5.69GB used out of 114GB total, which is expected. MacOS Disk Utility recognizes the drive as `/dev/disk2` and applies the branding ("USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1 Media"). It recognizes the existence of a 123.05GB ExFAT-formatted partition at `/dev/disk2s1`, but it can't mount it.

Comment: OK. I'd just be tempted to copy the data off it, reformat in the Mac [as MBR/ExFAT if you have to, though safer would always be GUID/HFS+ or even NTFS, but then you'd need corresponding read/write enabler software for the other platforms. Journaled formats are much, much more reliable] Either way, then try to throw files at it until you've filled more than 16GB & then eject & re-mount. I still have a suspicion it may not be 'real'. See https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/ for free testers.

Comment: Okay, I have h2testw running now. Will report back when it finishes. One other question; the drive gets hot when I use it, probably because it's made of metal. Could that be relevant?

Comment: It shouldn't if it's a reputable make; unless it's sitting out in the sun when it's already 42° in the shade.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. Also, H2testw finished without errors.

Comment: Also, @Tetsujin, I can't format the drive on macOS. `Couldn't open device (-69877)`

Comment: Ah, but FakeFlashTest did identify problems. Will update the post with details.

Comment: How much did it cost (roughly)?

Comment: @gronostaj Dunno, it was a gift. However, the link I posted in the question lists the exact model I (should) have. I don't know if this is where it was purchased.

Comment: Feels like your flash drive might be in the process of failing. Maybe something like a "cold solder joint" on one of the flash chips. The difference from one host device to another might be something unpredictable like how much heat transfer it absorbs from the host device via the shield of the USB connector, and how the related thermal expansion flexes the failing PCB.